# Not allowing to syncronize one of the fields

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, profile-sync

I have a question concerning syncronization of user profiles with AD. Is it possible to someone how to disable
syncronization of all properties from AD, because some fields i dont want to be imported ...
How is it possible to do?

And more info: it is a standard propertie "manager", so i cant delete it nor disable ... how to make sure it isnt being filled in on sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood your question. Please correct me if I have mistaken.

Before synchronizing user profile properties in AD, you will have to map the properties in AD to the properties in SharePoint user profile. If you do not provide a mapping or remove a mapping, ideally that particular column will not be imported.

Please [visit this msdn article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#MapUserProc) where each step to remove the mapping is explained.